# Gauke non-fullscreen mode went out of screen. How can I resize it back?

Tags: fullscreen, guake

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 and I don't know How I did this. But `gauke` dropdown menu became more than screen size and I can't resize it because bottom of `guake` is out of screen. I other word guake non-fullscreen mode is now bigger than full screen.

**Q**: How Can I resize such window(s) back in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options here:

- Remove its settings:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/guake
  ```
- Open *Guake*, make right mouse click on it, select *Preferences*, *General* tab, adjust *Main Window Height*, click *Close*.